# Show open cycle maps in Android Nutiteq API

Tags: dictionary, offline, cycle, nutiteq

Is it possible to show open cycle maps (not open street maps) with nutiteq?

Also I noticed in the library on [this link](http://www.nutiteq.com/nutiteq-sdk/downloads):

That there is no MBTilesMapLayer.java class. But there is in the AdvencedMap3D project. Is there a library for that too or how can I user the MBTiles for my Android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use more or less any tile source where provider has allowed it (which excludes Google).

```
mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(new TMSMapLayer(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, 6,
  "http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/", "/", ".png"));
```

This is added now to [Nutiteq Tile sources Wiki page](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Tile-Sources) also

For MBTiles you should use the MBTilesMapLayer.java from [AdvancedMap3D project](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/tree/master/AdvancedMap3D). This is up-to-date code and for most of the data source layers we keep open source code there, so you can tweak it for your needs.